# Android: context.startActivity not start the intended activity after reboot, it just open the app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using a 3rd-party library to receive push notifications. I am successful to make the push service auto-start and receive messages after phone reboot. But after reboot, click the notification cannot open the intended activity, it just open the app. If I have ever opened the app before clicking the  notification, this will work well. 
Here is my code to start the activity when click notification:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MsgDetailActivity.class);
i.putExtra("msg_id", msgId);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(i);
```

**EDIT**
When clicking the notification, the lib will send a broadcast. I have registered a receiver to receive the broadcast like this:

```
if (JPushInterface.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_OPENED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            //use the code above to open my acticity

   }
```

Here is my test result:

1. reboot phone -> open my app  -> (exit my app, or not) -> receive notification -> click notification -> open the intended activity (expected)
2. reboot phone -> receive notification -> click notification -> just open my app, not the intended activity. (not expected)

Comment: can you provide more details about the library you are using? And where did you put this code?

Comment: can you show us the creation of the PedingIntent? (you have to add a PendingIntent to the notification and not a simple Intent)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not sending "content-available: true" from server.
Add your info in the "data" payload.
And when starting the activity

```
       onCreate(Bundle b){
           onNewIntent(getIntent());
         }
       onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
         //bundle contains your data payload here.
       }
```